# ¿Por que el botón queda compactado o fuera de la pantalla en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, material-design

saben tengo una duda al respecto de porqué me queda en botón "Agregar" de esa forma, prácticamente es como si se saliera de la activity, incluso el texto "Agregue datos..." también queda mal debido a esto, he de decir que aún soy nuevo en todo esto del android studio, asi que cualquier cosa me podría ayudar, intenté harto pero no conseguí mostrar por completo el botón, solo la parte que se ve en la imagen (Probé usando LinearLayout también)

[image: Botón que queda Enterrado]

Me gustaría que quedara como se ve en la previsualización de Android Studio

[image: Botón con la forma esperada]

Agrego el codigo del XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_degradado"
    tools:context=".NuevoPacienteActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@string/agregue_datos_del_paciente"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout8"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout8"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout9"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextRutPa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_person_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/rutPa"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout9"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout10"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout8"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout8"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextNombrePa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_person_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/nombre"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout10"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout11"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout9"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout9"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextApellidoPa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_person_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/apellidos"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout11"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout12"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout10"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextEmailPa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_email_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/emailPa"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout12"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout13"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout11"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPhonePa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_phone_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/n_mero_de_celularPa"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout13"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout14"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout12"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextMotivoConsultaPa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_phone_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/motivo_de_consulta"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout14"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonAgregarPa"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout13"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextDiagnosticoPa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_phone_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                    android:hint="@string/diagnostico"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonAgregarPa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/agregarPa"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout14"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ¿Qué tal si en la altura del ConstraintLayout también escribes wrap_content?

Comment: Lo hice ahora que me dijiste, pero no cambia nada, se sigue manteniendo de la misma manera, también intenté cambiar los márgenes pero termina como saliéndose de la pantalla, así que realmente no sé porque está pasando, gracias por tu respuesta!